# grep/awk - how to filter out a certain keyword

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following line of text, where i want to filter out the N from (KEY_N) etc. Keep in mind that the N is not constant, it can be anything, like (KEY_J), (KEY_K), (KEY_L), (KEY_I), (KEY_SPACE) and so on..

> Event: time 1442439135.995248, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 49 (KEY_N), value 0

Comment: If you specify the question accurately, the answer becomes obvious.  If you mean that you want to remove all text between 'KEY_' and ')', then use `sed -e 's/KEY_[^)]*/KEY_/g'`.  If you mean something else, the solution will be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I hope that I got the question properly, if not then please let me know.

---

Having GNU grep you can use this:

```
grep -oP '.*\(\K[^)]+' file
```

An alternative on non GNU systems might be to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*(\([^)]\{1,\}\)).*/\1/' file
```